# Unable to use helper function in python on Kaggle notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, helper, kaggle

I am trying to upload my Jupyter notebook code on Kaggle notebook but am unable to import functions from helper.py file. The uploaded the folder including all .py and .csv files. The code is working fine on Jupyter but not on Kaggle. Please help me understand why its not working on Kaggle. I have a file named helper.py

```
import helper
biased_dataset = helper.bias_genre_rating_dataset(genre_ratings, 3.2, 2.5)
```

AttributeError: module 'helper' has no attribute 'get_genre_ratings'

if I change the file name to helper1.py

```
import helper1
biased_dataset = helper.bias_genre_rating_dataset(genre_ratings, 3.2, 2.5)
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helper1'

Is there any other way to access the functions from helper.py into my notebook?

Comment: Are you using `import helper` *inside* the file `helper.py`?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/95031

Comment: No, I'm using import helper in another file.